# How should I interpret the following set notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I am given a set M = {(a,b), (b,a)}, where M is a relation on a set B {a,b}

What would be the values of the set: M;M?

I know the answer is: {(a,a), (b,b)} but is it just the pair of each unique value. So if it was {(a,b,c), (b,a,c)} would the final answer include (c,c) also?

Comment: Are you asking about the definition of ;? Or do you have a definition of ; and are trying to understand how to apply it? Can you give some more context for the problem? I can *guess* that maybe you're talking about binary relations and composition of relations, but then the question you ask at the end wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @Hurkyl I have modified the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $M$ is a relation. Here, $M; M$ denotes [composition of relations](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aComposition_of_Relations):

$$(a,c) \in M;M \iff \exists b: (a,b) \in M \text{ and } (b,c) \in M$$

Can you work out why this results in $\{(a,a),(b,b)\}$ for your given $M$?

Comment: I have never in my life seen `;` used for composition. How did you guess?

Comment: @Asaf I have seen it several times; it originates from computer science (I've done some work bordering theoretical CS). $A; B$ is the same as $B \circ A$. Also, some authors use it as a "more natural" notation for commutative diagrams.